# why the async function doesn't return values?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `node.js` app with `websocket`

When the user get into `'/'` I need to send command message (json message) with web socket to other application.

When I get results from the other application, I need to return it.

It seems that I return empty results to the user, and I don't know why

`serv.js` file:

```
const websocket = require('ws')
async function sendData(command) {
  const ws = new websocket('ws://127.0.0.1:5678')
  ws.on('open', function open() {
     ws.send(JSON.stringfuly(command))
  });

  ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
    return data
  });

return {}
}

module.exports = {
  sendData,
}
```

`index.js` file:

```
connection = require('serv');

const router = Router();
.route('/')
.get(async(req, rep) => {
   // fill json command
   command = fillCommand()
   result = await connection.sendData(command)
   res.json(result);
})
```

I tried to debug, and I can see that `results = await connection.sendData(command)` get `{}` `result` only.

I tried to remove the `return {}` and I got the same results

I see that I'm getting results from the `ws.on('message'...` , But it is not get back to `index.js`

what am I missing and how can I fix it ?

Comment: _"...and I don't know why"_ - Because that's what you're doing here `return {}` which is the only return in `sendData()`.

Comment: You do `return {}`. I am not expert of websocket, but it seems that you should listen for `open` and `message` events instead.

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) (like `ws.on('message' , ...)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are returning the data inside the listener for the `message` event, which doesn't return the value from the async function. This kind of conversion from callbacks to promises can only be done with the `Promise` constructor.

```js
function sendData(command) {
  const ws = new websocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5678");
  ws.on("open", function open() {
    ws.send(JSON.stringfuly(command));
  });

  return new Promise( (res, rej) => {
    ws.on("message", (data) => {
      res(data);
    });

    // Don't forget to handle errors.
    ws.on("error", (error) => {
      rej(error);
    });
  });
}
```